# Execute on url change or on load

Tags: jquery, hash

I want to execute some ajax call when the hash changes but also on initial pageload.

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function (e) {
     //execute this code
});
if (window.location.hash) {
  $(window).trigger('hashchange')
}
```

But this executes only when there is a hash in the url `domain.com#hash`. If I load the pure url `domain.com` the code isn't executed.

How do I execute this on both possibilities, with and without hash?
(When the url is loaded without hash, there is some data displayed. With a has there is additional data displayed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want it to happen after page load:**

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

**Or if you want it to happen instantly** (not after load)

```
$(function() {
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

**This is then unnecessary**

```
if (window.location.hash) {
  $(window).trigger('hashchange')
}
```

Your code triggers `hashchange` only when there is a hash (`window.location.hash`) And when there is a hashchange you execute your function.

But if you want do it no matter if there is a hash or not, there is no need to check if it exists.

Comment: Thanks very much 